# Converting IE specific javascript with "for" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, jscript

I have the a form on my page and a script to go with it that works in IE. I need to get it working in Chrome. My code is below

```
<script for="Form1" event="onsubmit()" language="JScript">
        if (this.text1.value == '') 
        {
            alert ("Please enter the value")
            this.text1.focus()
            return false
        }

        this.hiddentext1.value = this.text1.value;

        // Disable button
        with ($('button1')) {
            value = "Processing ...";
            disabled = true;
        }


        return true;        
    </script>
```

The form is as follows:

```
    <form method="post" name="Form1" action="default.asp">

        <input type="hidden" name="hiddentext1">


        <input type="text" name="text1">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1">
    </form>
```

it works fine, submitting the form. But I also need to get it to work in Chrome, so I have to get rid of

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function ProcessField()
{
     alert("script gets called");
     alert("input value is " & this.text1.value);
        if (this.text1.value == '') 
        {
            alert ("Please enter the value")
            this.text1.focus()
            return false
        }

        this.hiddentext1.value = this.text1.value;

        // Disable button
        with ($('button1')) {
            value = "Processing ...";
            disabled = true;
        }


        return true;    
}   
    </script>
```

The form is as follows:

```
    <form method="post" name="Form1" action="default.asp" onsubmit="return processField();">

        <input type="hidden" name="hiddentext1">


        <input type="text" name="text1">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1">
    </form>
```

The script gets called but apparently crashes - "script gets called" part gets displayed but second alert does not fire. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is there a specific reason for not using with?

Comment: Main reason, it is slow, not allowed in strict mode.

Comment: any ideas what is wrong with my script?

Comment: You do not join strings with &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing up syntax for string concatenation with another language.

```
alert("input value is " & this.text1.value);
```

should be

```
alert("input value is " + this.text1.value);
```

and you probably will have an issue with disabling the button before the form submits. And `this` is the `window` and not the `form`.

```js
function processField(form)  //changed to lowercase p, pass in form
{  
     alert("script gets called");
     alert("input value is " + form.text1.value);  //changed & to +, updated this to form
        if (form.text1.value == '') //updated this to form
        {
            alert ("Please enter the value")
            form.text1.focus()  //updated form
            return false
        }

        form.hiddentext1.value = form.text1.value;  //updated this to form

        // Disable button
        with ($('button1')) {
            value = "Processing ...";
            disabled = true;
        }


        return true;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" name="Form1" action="default.asp" onsubmit="return processField(this);">  <!-- pass in this -->

        <input type="hidden" name="hiddentext1">


        <input type="text" name="text1">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1">
    </form>
```

Comment: that did not make a difference

Comment: There is an error in your console. "going to be something like 'can't read value of undefined`

Comment: why didn't "this" work instead of document.form or form?

Comment: Because "this" is the window object when you use inline event handlers. If you attached it with addEventListener, it would be a different result.

Comment: One more thing - at what point in my code should I attach addEventlistener? I understand that I have a lot of options but which is the best practice?

Comment: I tried using addEventListener but it still does not like "this" keyword